# Soap Core fails registering IFaultExceptionTransformer

Tags: .net-core, soap, soapcore

While starting a new SoapCore service and sending a dummy request with SoapUI, I receive a HTTP500 and the following exception:

`No service for type 'SoapCore.Extensibility.IFaultExceptionTransformer' has been registered.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `services.AddSoapCore();` to your services configuration

Comment: is that a solution ? I have to call a soap service with .Net core 5 what version did you use ?

Comment: I used soapui to test this service

Answer (score 2):

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` add this line
`services.TryAddSingleton<IFaultExceptionTransformer, DefaultFaultExceptionTransformer>();`

And the `DefaultFaultExceptionTransformer` is look something like this:

```
 public class DefaultFaultExceptionTransformer : IFaultExceptionTransformer
    {
        public Message ProvideFault(Exception exception, MessageVersion messageVersion, Message requestMessage, XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager)
        {
            return Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, "Exception", exception.ToString());
        }
    }
```

You can read more on this [here](https://justsimplycode.com/2020/02/02/soap-web-service-in-net-core-using-soapcore/).